# Getting active window url in crossrider

Tags: crossrider

I've been trying to track users current tab url, but I'm having some trouble doing this.

My current code

```
var activeTabUrl = null;
appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged(function(tabInfo) {
  activeTabUrl = tabInfo.tabUrl;
});
```

This code tracks active tab when user changes tab, but the problem is it doesn't track when a user changes url in the same tab. How can I track that?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are acquiring the URL in the extension's background scope and I presume you want to track the URL in the same scope. In this situation, I would use [appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate) using the same **activeTabUrl** variable to supplement your existing code, as follows:

```
appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(details) {
    // Where:
    //   * details.pageUrl is the URL of the tab requesting the page

    // Track Url
    activeTabUrl = details.pageUrl;
});
```

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: this only works for tab change, and doesn't work when you change a tab, and then change page url. How to get currently active tab  page url?

Comment: If you used the both methods, i.e. [appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-onTabSelectionChanged) and [appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate.addListener](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.webRequest.onBeforeNavigate-method-addListener) as proposed in the answer, you should find that it works. If yuo are still having an issue, please provide the code you are using. [**Disclosure**] I am a Crossrider employee

Answer (score 0):

i hope you can help me. i am using crossrider for the first time and need to write a plugin that detects images in the current webpage like imgur and pinterest. can you provide some starting point and API functions that i look at to implement my functionality, maybe like some high-level structure on how to approach this. would really appreciate ur help in this. :)